# How to set Oracle to deal with object names case-sensitively?

Tags: oracle

I know I can use double-quote to force case-sensitive object names, but I want to avoid using it. I wonder if there is a database option to set to make Oracle deal with object names in a case-sensitive manner without using double-quote. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such option.  If you want to force everything to be case-sensitive (and I would strongly question the wisdom of that), you would need to use double-quoted identifiers throughout your code.